# How to remove review order in onepage checkout option?

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.8

I want to remove review order option.

I want to "Place Order" event in payment information option. Means, If payment method selected then payment cycle should complete instead of Review Order comes.

I have tried and reasearch regarding this. But I am not getting solution.

Thank you

Comment: Was my answer useful? Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage::_getStepCodes()`. 
You need an observer that saves other after payment is selected. If you have 'terms and conditions' they have to be checked automatically.

You can checkout more on this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/how-can-i-remove-the-review-step-in-onepage-checkout

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have revise this link. But I am not getting how to create observer and rewrite block. I am new in magento.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the web about how to create a module and observer. If you have specific problems, you can ask them.